# How to submit form files on Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I would like to use Paw to send form files, that I can catch from my PHP script with the $_FILES global variable.

The File body option sends a file, but it is not encapsulated in a form structure and PHP cannot treat it.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Set your request to POST, which is likely to be the method you want to use
2. Go to the body tab, and pick Multipart on the left column
3. Enter the expected file name as "Part Name" (the key you want to get in your PHP `$_FILES` global)
4. In the Value field of the Multipart editor, right-click and pick File > File Content

[image: Pick file content for multipart in Paw]

5. Click on the *File* token, and you'll be able to pick or drag-and-drop a file

[image: Pick a file for multipart body in Paw]

6. Press Cmd + R (or Cmd + Enter) to send the request!